# Python Regex: non capturing group is captured

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I came up with these two regex patterns

1.

```
\([0-9]\)\s+([^.!?]+[.!?])
```

2.

```
[.!?]\s+([A-Z].*?[.!?])
```

To match sentences in strings like these:

> (1) A first sentence, that always follows a number in parantheses.
>   This is my second sentence. This is my third sentence, (...) .

Thanks to your answers I archived to get the intro sentence after the number in parantheses. I as well get the 2nd sentence with my 2nd regex.

However the third sentence is not captured, since the `.` was consumed before. My goal is to get the start point of these sentences by two methods:

1. Getting the "intro" sentence by capturing the start after `(1)`
2. Getting any other sentence by recognizing the dot, a whitespace and a Capital letter after it.

How can I avoid the matching to fail for the 3rd and following sentences?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` If you want to match 1 or more digits you could use `[0-9]+`

```
\([0-9]\)\s+([^.!?]+[.!?])
```

- `\([0-9]\)` Match a digit between parenthesis
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^.!?]+[.!?]` Match 1+ times any char other than `.`, `!`,`?`. Then match one of them.
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s26A6x/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mqYaWM)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\([0-9]\)\s+([^.!?]+[.!?])"
test_str = "(1) This is my first sentence, it has to be captured. This is my second sentence."

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['This is my first sentence, it has to be captured.']
```

---

If you want to match the other sentences as well and be able to differentiate between the first sentence and the others, you might use an alternation with another capturing group

```
(?:\([0-9]\)\s+([^.!?]+[.!?])|([A-Z].*?\.)(?: |$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LJy8Iz/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This actually works with the first sentence. I had to update my question, since I can into a similiar issues right after that, maybe you can help with that?

Comment: @errorinpersona Do you mean like this? `(?:\([0-9]\)\s+([^.!?]+[.!?])|([A-Z].*?\.)(?: |$))` https://regex101.com/r/LJy8Iz/1 The starting sentence is in group 1, the other sentences in group 2.

Comment: @errorinpersona I have updated the answer with the last pattern and added an explanation.

Comment: Uff, is there a way to exclude . where the char before it is a number? "A sentence with a list 1. bullet one 2. bullet two."

Comment: @errorinpersona You could prepend a word boundary `\b[A-Z]` or a negative lookbehind `(?<![0-9])[A-Z]` or `(?<!\S)[A-Z]`

Comment: So I tried your negative lookbehind and now it does not capture it anymore, but it does not capture the first alternative at all: https://regex101.com/r/Nf5ddA/2

Comment: @errorinpersona Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/mBc7Nd/1 with the lookbehind before the character class `[A-Z]`

Comment: That is what I had before but the part "Arbeitsbevölkerung, 2. die" must not be split. It is one sentence. So the "2. die" must no be seen as the end of the first capturing group, because there is a 2 before the dot, i.e. capturing has to go on. The sentence end at "Asylbegehrenden und ihrer Unterbringung." Thank you soo much for your help! :)

Comment: @errorinpersona Then the dot inbetween will not pass the negated character class `[^.!?]` Perhaps you could use this https://regex101.com/r/mQXTht/1 and make the dot match a newline using `re.DOTALL`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206657/discussion-between-errorinpersona-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 1):

You can use your existing regex, just placing a group around the sentence part (`.*?[.!?]`) and getting group 1 from the output of `re.match`:

```
import re

para = '(1) This is my first sentence, it has to be captured. This is my second sentence.'
print(re.search(r'\([0-9]\)\s+(.*?[.!?])', para).group(1))
```

Output:

```
This is my first sentence, it has to be captured.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to do this.
The first one is **lookbehind**. You should replace `':'` with `'<='`.
Unfortuantely it does not support variable length patterns. So just one space allowed

```
ss='(1) This is my first sentence, it has to be captured. This is my second sentence.'

re.search(r'(?<=\([0-9]\)\s).*?[.!?]', ss).group(0)
```

Output:

```
'This is my first sentence, it has to be captured.'
```

You can also search for a group:

```
re.search(r'\([0-9]\)\s+(.*?[.!?])', ss).group(1)
```

Output:

```
'This is my first sentence, it has to be captured.'
```

It allows variable length patterns

Both options with minimum modifications of your original pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question as it seems as I'm running straigt into the next issue :/